# Embedding youtube video "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, embed

I'm trying to embed a youtube video on to my page once the user gives the link to the video.

```
<iframe width=\'560\' height=\'315\' src='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video id>&amp;output=embed' frameborder=\'0\' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But when I try to add this I get this error. After inspecting the page in chrome, I see this error in the console tab

"Refused to display document because of the display is forbidden by X-Frame-Options"

I'm not able to see the video even in `IE` and `Firefox` also

I even tried adding the

```
 header('X-Frame-Options:Allow-From http://www.youtube.com'); 
 header('X-Frame-Options:GOFORIT);
 &amp;output=embed to the url
```

After reading certain solutions in other posts.

But I still get the same error.

I also see that the youtube has the method of object embedding to show the video, but already youtube has made that as old method of embedding the video. So I want to use the new iframe method of embedding the video on to my page.

**Problem is seen in**

- Firefox 11
- Chrome 18.0
- IE 8

Anybody faced this problem?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The page you're setting as the source of the iframe (the Youtube `/watch` page) doesn't want to be embedded in your page. You cannot force it to let you do that.

The correct URL to embed is of the form:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/<video-id>
```

In your case

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0
```

Comment: @KNU `youtube.com/v/` is the old Flash player. It's best to not use that anymore -- it won't run on mobile devices, for instance.

Comment: Ok In my case, I couldn't do inside the iframe, how to do in the .htaccess?

Comment: @Keynes I think you're confused. This issue has nothing to do with .htaccess files, and cannot be solved with one.

Answer (score 7):

When you copy a video link off YouTube: `"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fva3fgKmu3o"`

- Replace '**watch**' with '**embed**'
- Remove '?v='

Final Example: `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fva3fgKmu3o"`

Comment: the best answer, I searched for days for a solution for dynamic embed with iframe and that solved it first.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the keyword watch?v= with embed and change the live URL something like this:-

```
$url_string="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1pTkatn6sI";
$url= str_replace('watch?v=','embed/', $url_string);
```

And then embed it in the iframe

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="{{ $url }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Someone has mentioned the url should `embed` instead `watch`.

If someone looking for Javascript answer, we can fix this dynamically by using `string.replace()`

for example

```
const updateYoutubeUrl = (youtube_url = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1pTkatn6sI') => {
   youtube_url.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/')
   return youtube_url
}
```

please refer @dhahn answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the `embed` url generate from the `Share` section, not the ordinary `url`.

1. Press the `Share` button:

[image]

2. Press the `embed` button:

[image]

3. Use the `url` inside the `iframe` (or use the entire `iframe`):

[image]

Source: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** You may need to delete your cookies.

---

If it still doesn't work with either `/v` or `/embed`, the issue may be on your client, because of malformatted cookies. You can also see this error because of a **400 HTTP ERROR** on most or every YouTube pages.

To fix this issue you'll have to delete YouTube cookies:

> In Chrome, enter `chrome://settings/siteData` in the address bar, and enter `youtube` in the `Search cookies` box.
>
> Next, you will see two groups of cookies for youtube, you could remove all, OR if you click the little arrow, you will be able to see the individual cookie names, and could just delete specific ones like all the `gsScrollPos-####`.

Sources of this answer and more details can be found on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/6h59hh/400_thats_an_error_on_every_youtube_page/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the official doc at [Embed a video or playlist](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780) from support.google.com/youtube

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG"
frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Check [more tips, tricks about youtube](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/06/tips-tricks-about-youtube.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML code
don't copy the exact video link but right click and copy embed code and paste in `src" "`

```
<div class="example">
 src="<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jH0Q8NOsIR8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>" </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get id from youtube link this is helped me for nuxtjs

```
<iframe          
 :src="`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${getIdFromURL(group.videoEmbedLink)}?rel=0`"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen
  loading="lazy"
/>
```

...

```
methods: {
    getIdFromURL(url) {
      const youtubeRegexp = /https?:\/\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:['"][^<>]*>|<\/a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*/ig
      let id = url.replace(youtubeRegexp, '$1')

      if (id.includes(';')) {
        const pieces = id.split(';')

        if (pieces[1].includes('%')) {
          const uriComponent = decodeURIComponent(pieces[1])
          id = `http://youtube.com${uriComponent}`.replace(youtubeRegexp, '$1')
        } else {
          id = pieces[0]
        }
      } else if (id.includes('#')) {
        id = id.split('#')[0]
      }

      return id
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your site uses the Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy header, you need to add 'credentialless' to your iframe element

```
<iframe credentialless ... >
```

see https://developer.chrome.com/blog/iframe-credentialless/

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that your URL contains the word `embed` like this link:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/EdxSS-1c-cU?si=6pejqm2Qaa4l76YD

**AND NOT** like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch/EdxSS-1c-cU

You need to add the header `X-Frame-Options` with the value `SAMEORIGIN`, regarding to this documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Example:

If you are working with React you can add it to your HTTP interceptor:

```
  axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  request.headers={'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'}
  return request })
```

I highly recommend referring to the documentation mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

just add embed instead of watch

example:-https://youtube.com/embed/OGGuw2dLBjk