# Showing YouTube videos in an iFrame

Tags: video, iframe, youtube

I want to show YouTube videos through an iFrame on my page, but if I set the iFrame src to the YouTube URL, I get blocked because X-Frames-Options is set to sameorigin. I did find one YouTube video that works.  If I set my iFrame src to https://www.youtube.com/embed/LSHuGxB3tTU it plays fine.  The key seems to be the embed/ directory.  Do all YouTube videos have a version in an embed/ directory that I could pull and show?  I don't see anything in the video settings on the YouTube page that mentions embed/.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding youtube video "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934944/embedding-youtube-video-refused-to-display-document-because-display-forbidden-b)

Answer (score 4):

> *" If I set my iFrame src to **https://www.youtube.com/embed/LSHuGxB3tTU** it plays fine.
>  The key seems to be the `embed/` directory"*

The whole point of embedding Youtube videos in another, is that `iFrames` are used to display their player interface (and run its supporting code). This is done by accessing the embedable player/code by using an iFrame.

- Go to any Youtube video and click **`SHARE`**.
- In the Share options, click **`EMBED`** and it generates the iFrame code to *copy/paste* on your site.

> *"Do all YouTube videos have a version in an embed/ directory that I could pull and show?"*

Yes every Youtube video upload gets an embed link auto-generated, just like the video part has multiple resolutions auto-generated downwards from the input size (*example:* a video of height `360` also generates `240` and `144` sized videos).

To get embed URL (usable in  iFrame) :

Use : `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` followed by the `VIDEO_ID`.

Example:

- Taking [`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJOfJdWGPMk`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJOfJdWGPMk).
- Where`VIDEO_ID` = `wJOfJdWGPMk`.
- The iFrame / Embed URL is : [`https://www.youtube.com/embed/wJOfJdWGPMk`](https://www.youtube.com/embed/wJOfJdWGPMk)